# Terminology for cubical boundary

Tags: higher-category-theory

In globular higher category theory, an $(n+1)$-cell is shaped like the $(n+1)$-disk $D^{n+1}$, and its boundary has the shape of the $n$-sphere $S^n$, given by two glued $n$-disks.

In cubical higher category theory, an $(n+1)$-cell is shaped like the $(n+1)$-cube $I^{n+1}$, and its boundary is given by a number of glued $n$-cubes. Is there a standard name for this boundary?

Comment: Of course the geometric realization of this boundary is also a sphere.  So what about "cubical sphere"?

Comment: I guess the trouble with that is it's 3 syllables, which feels like a mouthful during collaboration discussions. If there's no short standard term I'm tempted to make something up, like "shell", which is at least monosyllabic and phonetically close to "sphere". I think I mostly wanted to check there wasn't a standard term I was ignorant of -- I guess not.

Comment: If everything in sight is cubical, so there's no danger of confusion, you could just say "sphere".

Comment: Sure, I agree that would be acceptable in that case. In this project, however, we're constantly moving between the cubical and globular perspectives, so we need to be able to disambiguate.